# Spectral norm of infinite sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following arises in statistical time-series analysis but, as far as I can tell, my question is purely mathematical.

Suppose I have a positive definite matrix $C$ that satisfies
$$
C = ACA' + V,
$$

where $A$ has all eigenvalues less than one in absolute terms and $V$ is a positive definite matrix. I believe this is sufficient for $C$ to have the infinite sum representation $C = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}A^kV(A')^k$ based on what little I know about Lyapunov equations.

I want to assess the spectral norm of $C^{-1}$. For example, how does it relate to the spectral norm of $V$?

Answer (score 2):

Since both $V$ and $C$ is symmetric and positive definite, we find for a vector $x$:
$$
x^TCx  =(Ax)^T C (Ax) + x^TVx \ge x^TVx.
$$
Thus, the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_n(C)$ of $C$ is $\ge$ the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_n(V)$ of $V$. This implies $\|C^{-1}\|\le \lambda_n(C)^{-1}\le \lambda_n(V)^{-1}$: Let $y=C^{-1}x$, then
$$
\|C^{-1}y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 \le \lambda_n(C)^{-1}x^TCx =  \lambda_n(C)^{-1}y^TC^{-1}y,
$$
hence $\|C^{-1}y\|\le \lambda_n(C)^{-1}\|y\|$. Thus,
$$
\|C^{-1}\|\le \lambda_n(C)^{-1}\le \lambda_n(V)^{-1}.
$$